# When IBOutlet components of NSWindow are initialized?

Tags: initialization, nib, nswindow, iboutlet

I show modal subclassed window:

```
NSWindowController* controller = [[NSWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName: @"MyWindow"];
[NSApp runModalForWindow: [controller window]];
```

And I override `initWithContentRect:(NSRect)contentRect styleMask:(NSUInteger)aStyle backing:(NSBackingStoreType)bufferingType defer:(BOOL)flag` in my window subclass to setup children views which are linked to nib file. But these children are not initialized at this moment (are nil).

Where to place my initialization code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nib/xib loader creates the objects (with some of the constructrors from `init` family) and setups their outlets in an undefined order. After they all exists and all the outlets are set up, then it sends `awakeFromNib` to all objects from nib/xib files (which accept this message) so this is the right place where to perform most of the initialization.